# SharePoint 2013 Background-Color Not Rendering in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am developing a SP13 site. IE8 does not render the background color of the title bar. It works fine in 9, 10, & other browsers. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

**CSS**

```
 .title
 {
   background-color: rgb(154, 153, 152);
 }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="title">
   <div class="logo"></div>
   <div class="search"></div>
 </div>
```

In the developer tools, I can see the style being applied to the element but it clearly does not render. The background color renders as white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently IE adds this class when it detects IE8.

```
.ms-core-needIEFilter
{
   display: block;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr=#d8ffffff,endColorstr=#d8ffffff);
   background-color: transparent;
}
```

This causes the background color to be overwritten. If you apply `!important` to your style, the `filter` property distorts your background color. You have to overwrite all these in your class.

**Solution**

```
 .your-class
 {
   filter: !important;
   background-color: #0000 !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `background`: instead of `background-color`:

```
 .title
 {
   background: rgb(154, 153, 152);
 }
```

source: http://css-tricks.com/ie-background-rgb-bug/